# How to style selected element inside map function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put style on the selected div onClick

```
 let woods =  pageURL.map( (wood, key)=> {

        if(wood.internal_doors_style[0] ===  this.state.slug_style) {
         if(this.state.selected) {
                   sel = 'red'
            }
            return (

                <div style={{background: sel}}  key={wood.id}  className="menu-item wood-item filter-wood" id={wood.id}  onClick={()=> this.setW(wood.internal_doors_wood[0])}>
                    <img src={wood.acf.wood_image.url} alt="" width="40"/>
                    <span className="span">{wood.acf.woods_title}</span>
                </div>

            )
        }
    })
```

the problem I am having that the style is applying on all the element not the selected one only.

```
  this.setState({
        slug_wood: w,
        selected: !this.state.selected


    })
    return single_data =  <SingleInternal wood={this.state.slug_wood} style={ this.state.slug_style}/>


}
```

is there a way maybe to target the id of each element where I set the id of each element to be unique id={wood.id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the id of the selected element in the `state variable` and every time you select an element change the `state variable` to the `selected id` then inside the map check if the value of the selected id is equal to the element id or not if yes then set the selected element style otherwise set the style to unset. Considering `selectedId` to be the name of the state variable and onClick `setState`:

```
 let woods =  pageURL.map( (wood, key)=> {

        let sel=unset
        if(this.state.selectedId === wood.id){
            sel = 'red' 
           }
            return (

                <div style={{background: sel}}  key={wood.id}  className="menu-item wood-item filter-wood" id={wood.id}  onClick={()=> this.setState({selectedId: wood.id})}>
                    <img src={wood.acf.wood_image.url} alt="" width="40"/>
                    <span className="span">{wood.acf.woods_title}</span>
                </div>

            )
        }
    })
```

Comment: Im having trouble understanding this